# LinkedIn apply button not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I've created new app in the LinkedIn developer website, and inserted this code on my website:

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: MY_API_CODE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<script type="IN/Share"></script> <br>

<script type="IN/Login"></script>

<br/><br/>
<script type="IN/Apply" data-email="test@example.com" data-jobTitle="Testing"      data-companyID="1337"></script>
```

Both share and login buttons are shown but not the apply button.

Can someone tell me what the problem here is?

Comment: Have you tried checking the console to see if there's any errors displayed?

Comment: Yes, but there is no error, as you can see, the other bottons work fine

Comment: There is no solution?????

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you ever cure it?